# Python - build a function based on json input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code in a Python module

```
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset( _('Basic Information'), Field('form_filler', css_class='enabler'), Div('form_filler_other', css_class='dependent'), 'child_dob','age', 'sex', Field('country', css_class='enabler'), Div('zip_code', css_class='dependent'),'birth_order', Field('multi_birth_boolean', css_class='enabler'), Div('multi_birth', css_class='dependent'), self.birth_weight_field, Field('born_on_due_date', css_class='enabler'), Div('early_or_late', 'due_date_diff', css_class='dependent')),
        Fieldset( _('Family Background'), Field('primary_caregiver', css_class='enabler'), Div('primary_caregiver_other', css_class='dependent'), 'mother_yob', 'mother_education',Field('secondary_caregiver', css_class='enabler'), Div('secondary_caregiver_other', css_class='dependent'), 'father_yob', 'father_education', 'annual_income'),
        Fieldset( _("Child's Ethnicity"),HTML("<p> " + ugettext("The following information is being collected for the sole purpose of reporting to our grant-funding institute, i.e.,  NIH (National Institute of Health).  NIH requires this information to ensure the soundness and inclusiveness of our research. Your cooperation is appreciated, but optional.") + " </p>"), 'child_hispanic_latino', 'child_ethnicity'),
        Fieldset( _("Caregiver Information"), 'caregiver_info'),
        Fieldset( _("Language Exposure"), Field('other_languages_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div(Field('other_languages', css_class='make-selectize'),'language_from', 'language_days_per_week', 'language_hours_per_day', css_class='dependent')),
        Fieldset( _("Health"), 
            Field('ear_infections_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('ear_infections', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('hearing_loss_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('hearing_loss', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('vision_problems_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('vision_problems', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('illnesses_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('illnesses', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('services_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('services', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('worried_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('worried', css_class='dependent'),
            Field('learning_disability_boolean', css_class = 'enabler'), Div('learning_disability', css_class='dependent'),
        ),
    )
```

I want to replace this and build it using a JSON input file so I created this file (I'm only showing the first Fieldset).

```
[{
    "fieldset" : "Basic Information",
    "fields" : [
        {
            "field" : "form_filler",
            "div" : ["form_filler_other"]
        },{
            "field" : "child_dob"
        },{
            "field" : "age"
        },{
            "field" : "sex"
        },{
            "field" : "country", 
            "div" : ["zip_code"]
        },{
            "field" : "birth_order"
        }, {
            "field" : "multi_birth_boolean",
            "div" : ["multi_birth"]
        }, {
            "field" : "self.birth_weight_field"
        }, {
            "field" : "born_on_due_date", 
            "div" : ["early_or_late", "due_date_diff"]
        }

    ]
}
]
```

And this code:

```
    rows = []
    fieldsets = json.load(open(self.filename))
    for fieldset in fieldsets:
        fields = []
        for field in fieldset['fields']:
            if 'div' in field:
                this_field = Field(field['field'], css_class="enabler"), Div(lambda x,: x in field['div'], css_class="dependent"),
            else:
                this_field = field['field'],
            fields.append(this_field)

        rows.append(Fieldset(fieldset['fieldset'], lambda field: field in fields))
    x = lambda row,: row in rows
    self.helper.layout = Layout(x)
```

With hindsight this obviously doesn't work, giving this erro:

```
WARNING:root:Could not resolve form field '<function <lambda> at 0x7f8f3acab668>'.
```

How can I build this code dynamically based on the json input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are understanding what lambda does.  It is creating an dynamically generated anonymous function.  So your code is creating a function to pass as the first argument to Div.  And in other places it looks like you are assuming it is needed to do list comprehension.

It looks like what you really want is to just flatten the list in field['div'] so that instead of passing a list as the first argument to Div you are passing each member of the list as a subsequent positional argument to Div.

Consider

```
>>> def f(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
...     print(a)
...     print(b)
...     print(c)
...     print(d)
... 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> f(lambda a,: a in x, d='a')
<function <lambda> at 0x7faee8124758>
None
None
a
>>> f(x, d='a')
[1, 2, 3]
None
None
a
>>> f(*x, d='a')
1
2
3
a
>>>
```

The last is what you want, so replacing

```
Div(lambda x,: x in field['div'], css_class="dependent")
```

with just

```
Div(*field['div'], css_class="dependent")
```

should get your Fieldset arguments.  Then you just call Fieldset on that list in a similar way.  Something like:

```
rows = []
fieldsets = json.load(open(self.filename))
for fieldset in fieldsets:
    fields = []
    for field in fieldset['fields']:
        if 'div' in field:
            this_field = Field(field['field'], css_class="enabler"), Div(*field['div'], css_class="dependent"),
        else:
            this_field = field['field'],
        fields.append(this_field)

    rows.append(Fieldset(fieldset['fieldset'], *fields)
self.helper.layout = Layout(x)
```

Hmm.  Actually I think you then still have problems.  This doesn't call the underscore function on your first Fieldset argument, and it looks like you need some additional work on some of your field values, but this gets you past the lambda conundrum.

**EDIT**

The above took me part way there, and this was the working solution:

```
    rows = []
    fieldsets = json.load(open(self.filename))
    for fieldset in fieldsets:
        fields = []
        for field in fieldset['fields']:
            if 'div' in field:
                fields.append(Field(field['field'], css_class="enabler"))
                fields.append(Div(*field['div'], css_class="dependent"))
            else:
                fields.append(field['field'])

        rows.append(Fieldset(fieldset['fieldset'], *fields))
    self.helper.layout = Layout(*rows)
```